# Como puedo manejar un error cuando una propiedad no existe en php

Tags: php, php7

Supongamos que a traves del llamado a una api propia envían esta información:

```
$body = {"correo": "correo@correo.com", "contrasena": "123456"};
```

Se asigna a $usuario:

```
$usuario = json_decode($body);
```

y en el código se desean tomar los valores:

```
$email = $usuario->email;
$password = $usuario->password;
```

Como en el json vienen las claves ***correo*** y ***contrasena*** y se esta tratando de accesar a las propiedades ***email*** y ***password***

Aparece un error Undefined property: stdClass::$correo

Como puedo manejar ese error para poder enviar un mensaje que están incorrectos los nombres de los campos del json?

Lo intente con try catch pero no funciono.

```
try {
      $correo = $usuario->usr_correo;
      $contrasena = $usuario->usr_pwd;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      throw new ExcepcionApi(self::ESTADO_FALLA_DESCONOCIDA, "Error en los parámetros");
    }
```

Comment: Parece que estás en el contexto de un objeto ¿? Entonces es más fácil levantar una excepción en ese caso, pero necesitamos ver el objeto completo.

Comment: Es el metodo login de un objeto usuarios que es parte de una API, el $body se obtiene con un `file_get_contents('php://input');` posteriormente se obtienen los valores de **correo y contrasena** (en el supuesto que el cliente los haya enviado bien) para enviarlos como parámetros a otro método que valide al usuario. Gracias por tu pronta respuesta @A.Cedano

Comment: Prueba con https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.property-exists.php es como el isset, pero para propiedades de objetos.

Comment: Entonces puedes mapear el JSON al objeto y poner en el objeto métodos `__set` y `__get` donde verifiques si la propiedad no existe lanzando una excepción. Mira algunos ejemplos [en esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17236189/5587982).

Answer (score 2):

en primer lugar PHP no maneja tipo de datos clave-valor (No es Javascript ni Python), en su lugar usa arreglos asociativos u objetos, por lo cual el que tu quieras crear una variable así es incorrecto. La sintaxis correcta sería pasarlo como cadena y PHP se encargue de transformarlo, quedaría así

```
$body = '{"correo": "correo@correo.com", "contrasena": "123456"}';
```

Cuando utilizas `json_decode()` este crea un objeto y estás sacando las variables de forma correcta, pero lo parsearemos a un arreglo para buscar las claves que necesitas

```
$usuario = (array) json_decode( $body );
$keys    = array_keys( $usuario );
```

Ahora podemos hacer una busqueda de las claves que son necesarias, si no vienen tal cual entonces levantamos una excepción. Caso contrario continuamos

```
if( array_search( 'email', $keys ) === false || array_search( 'password', $keys ) === false ) {
    throw new Exception("Error en los parámetros");
} else {
    echo 'STUFF!';
}
```

Con eso puedes controlar que la información que venga de fuera sea en el formato correcto, te dejo la documentación de las funciones

[array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php)

[array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php)

Así luciría tu código completo

```
$body    = '{"email": "correo@correo.com", "password": "123456"}';
$usuario = (array) json_decode( $body );
$keys    = array_keys( $usuario );


if( array_search( 'email', $keys ) === false || array_search( 'password', $keys ) === false ) {
    throw new Exception("Error en los parámetros");
} else {


  echo 'STUFF!';
}
```

Comment: Hacer esto es involucionar. Se trata de un objeto, y PHP tiene [`property_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.property-exists.php) para verificar si una propiedad existe en un objeto. Aparte de eso, se puede verificar la existencia de cada propiedad mediante los métodos mágicos `__get` y `__set` en el caso de querer levantar una excepción cuando cualquier propiedad no exista. Es lo que entendí que el OP quería, leyendo la pregunta y el contexto. No me parece justo degradar el objeto a array para hacer esta comprobación por lo demás limitada.

Comment: Ya probe la solución que comenta @Alberto Siurob y si funciona, ahora bien coincido en que lo que deseo es levantar una excepción para no tener que degradar el objeto, si me puedes dar un poco de luz para buscarle lo agradecería A. Cedano

Comment: Ya probe el property_exist y funciono de igual manera, gracias a todos por su valiosa ayuda. El código quedo de la siguiente manera:

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php):

```
if (isset($usuario->email) && isset($usuario->password)){
  //hacer algo
}else{
  echo "no se encontraron esos valores";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$usuario =  json_decode($body);

if ( !property_exists($usuario,'correo') || !property_exists($usuario,'contrasena')) {
                throw new ExcepcionApi(self::ESTADO_FALLA_DESCONOCIDA, "Error en los parámetros");
    }
```